# Gallery not showing up after executing Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have gallery with images and paragraphs(Titles for images). 
When you open the link you will see all pictures with titles but as soon you search something pictures disappeared. Any suggestion on how to fix this?
https://lazartest1.myshopify.com/pages/testtesttest This is code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

    });
  });
});
// ]]></script>
```

HTML:

Comment: The webpage is password protected.

Comment: I have removed password...

Comment: After searching `display:none;` is added to all the img tags. Probably because of your jQuery selector `#myDIV *`. Try changing the selector to `#myDiv .img-box`.

Comment: I just tested it and it seemed to work... so added it as an answer

Comment: gallery bottom Are you using carousel slider its not working  right?

Comment: Multiple jQuery library having so conflicted check

Comment: Why you are using multiple library?

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery selector to only target the elements you need.
ie, change `$("#myDIV *")` to `$("#myDIV .img-box")`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV .img-box").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed $("#myDIV *") to $("#myDIV .img-box") and everthing works perfect! Thank you so much!